# German spellchecker

Tags: windows, linux, spell-check

I'm in a German class, and I have to write my assignments in German. I'm looking for good, free German spellchecker program which could be either online or offline?

I'm using Windows and Linux, and any browser extension also works.

Comment: For which OS you want for? Any browser extension is sufficient for you or not?

Comment: @avirk See my edited question :)

Comment: Sorry, but we don't do product recommendations. There are probably dozens of spell checking programs available, plus online services. It shouldn't be too hard to find one – see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Free_spelling_checking_programs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Chrome extension [After the deadline](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/after-the-deadline/fcdjadjbdihbaodagojiomdljhjhjfho) and anothrer is [Spell checker for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/spell-checker-for-chrome/jfpdnkkdgghlpdgldicfgnnnkhdfhocg/details).

**After the deadline** checks English, French, German, Portuguese, and Spanish text.